# NUnit 3.2.0 Console Execution

Tags: c#, nunit, regression

I am trying to run multiple categories from nunit console. In version below 3.0 i was running it as

nunit.exe  "mydll.dll" /run /include=Category1,Category2

I would like to use it similarly using nunit 3.2.0. Any idea how do i use it? I understood that /include option has been replaced in version 3.0 above and should be used as --where. Here is how i am trying to run it.

Below are options tried with no luck.

```
nunit3-console.exe "mydll.dll" --where:cat==Category1,Category2
nunit3-console.exe "mydll.dll" --where:cat==Category1&&Category2
nunit3-console.exe "mydll.dll" --where:cat==Category1||Category2
```

can someone help me in executing multiple categories in one go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To join multiple conditions together, you need each to be an actual condition - so I think you want:

```
--where:cat==Category1||cat==Category2
```

Or more readably IMO:

```
"--where:cat == Category1 || cat == Category2"
```

The quoting *may* be necessary to stop the shell from expecting "|" to be important, too.

This works fine for me. Demo:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

public class TestDemo
{
    [Test, Category("X")]
    public void TestX()
    {
    }

    [Test, Category("Y")]
    public void TestY()
    {
    }

    [Test, Category("Z")]
    public void TestZ()
    {
    }
}
```

Compile:

```
csc /target:library /r:nunit.framework.dll TestDemo.cs
```

Run:

```
nunit3-console.exe TestDemo.dll "--where:cat==X || cat==Y"
```

Result:

```
Test Count: 2, Passed: 2, Failed: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: Both options are not working. I am not sure what is that i am doing wrong

Comment: @RajanPhatak: What exactly do you observe?

Comment: It always provide me the execution help

Comment: @RajanPhatak: And does it do that for a single filter? Additionally, do you mean 3.2.0 of NUnit? I can't find a version 3.0.2 to download...

Comment: Try switching it to --where "cat == Category1 || cat == Category2" although Jon's answer works for me with NUnit 3.2, at least in PowerShell.

Comment: @RajanPhatak: Have just edited the answer based on my Noda Time Travis build - it's possible you need `=` instead of `:` after `--where`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, `--where ` `--where:` and `--where=` should all work. I just tried all of your variations in the NUnit project and none give me the help.

Comment: @RobProuse: Thanks for that - will revert back then. Which exact version were you using? That may be the key...

Comment: @JonSkeet no.. It doesn't

Comment: @JobSkeet does it require to be powershell script? I am creating it as batch file

Comment: @RajanPhatak: It shouldn't do. But I'm not going to be able to help reproduce this unless you answer my earlier question about the exact version you're using. (I can't find 3.0.2 to download.)

Comment: @RajanPhatak: It would be worth editing your question then. I can't reproduce the problem though - try the demo I've provided.

Comment: @JonSkeet I could resolve my issue. Issue was that i was using Notepad++ to create a bat file. As my path had spaces, i had used " in the path and when i was running command from command prompt, it was not reading the character " correctly. Hence it was not finding any parameters and hence the issue. Thanks for help though

Comment: @JonSkeet, I am using the dev version 3.3 of NUnit, but we haven't changed any of the `--where` behaviour since 3.0.1. Even then, it was small bug fixes.